# fileNotFoundException: EROFS in android

Tags: android, csv

I'm trying to create a .csv file in an android app. The app is supposed to create the file if there is none, or replace the file if it already exist. I tried to use the `FileWriter`, but it doesn't create the file and throws the `'FileNotFoundException: open failed: EROFS'` exception.

I've already done some research, but I really can't find it. I have the permission in the manifest file (`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />`) and the app folder is not open in any other app.

(I know there is opencsv, but since this is the only thing I need to do, I don't think I really need it.)

Here's my code:

```
    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter("data.csv");
        for(Answer answer: answerList) {
            writer.append(answer.getName());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(answer.getTime());
            writer.append('\n');
        }                
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
writer = new FileWriter("data.csv");
```

to

```
writer = new FileWriter(getFilesDir()+File.separatorChar+"data.csv");
```

This will create the file in the internal storage.

You need to give the full path to where you want to create the file or where it exists already.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally found it! Do you have any idea where I can find the .csv file? It is not in the directionary I put it in. (I'm trying with emulator)

Comment: It will be in the internal storage.

Comment: I'm trying on a real device now, but I still can't find the file. `getFilesDir()` gives me a path I cannot follow in the internal storage folder my computer opens. Then where do I have to look?